# Need help integrating NCover 3.4 into CruiseControl.Net 1.5 with xUnit 1.6.1

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ncover, xunit.net

I'm trying to integrate NCover into my CC.net build. I followed an article I found here http://csut017.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/improved-ncover-integration/ that I pretty much followed verbatim except that we use xUnit instead of nUnit for our unit tests. The problem is NCover never runs on the build server with this configuration and I was wondering if anyone else had some experience with this and could give me some advice.

Below is the pertinent parts of my ccnet.config file. The `<msbuild>` portion of the config is running our unit tests which have been configured right in the proj files.

```
<msbuild>
    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>c:\projects\win_wip\src\Core.Tests</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Core.Tests.csproj</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:configuration=debug</buildArgs>
    <targets>Test</targets>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
    <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>              

<ncoverProfile>
    <executable>c:\program files\ncover\ncover.console.exe</executable>
    <program>C:\Projects\win_wip\lib\xunit-1.6.1\xunit.console.clr4.x86.exe</program>
    <testProject>DomainModel.Tests.dll</testProject>
    <workingDir>c:\projects\win_wip\src\domainmodel.tests\bin\debug</workingDir>
    <includedAssemblies>domainmodel.*.dll</includedAssemblies>
</ncoverProfile>

<ncoverReport>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\NCover\NCover.Reporting.exe</executable>
    <outputDir>ncover\reports</outputDir>
    <reports>
        <report>FullCoverageReport</report>
    </reports>
    <sortBy>CoveragePercentageDescending</sortBy>
</ncoverReport>
```

Comment: You can look into the ccnet logs (in CCNETDir\server\logs) to find more information.

Comment: I've looked at the logs... NCover never actually runs.. I even watched the machine with process explorer and ncover.console.exe never fires during the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the documentation at http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/continuous-integration/cruisecontrol-net/?

Comment: I haven't modified my msbuild because on our local dev machines we don't use NCover (we use dotCover), so I didn't want to add NCover specific configurations in there.

Comment: I did end up using NCover this way. Apparently the way I was trying to include ncover wasn't quite working in cc.net yet.